# Is it possible to hide bing maps WPF control by setting visible = false?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing-maps

I'm trying to place images over a map and then remove the map so all I can see is the pictures. Is there a way to do this with the bing maps WPF example shown here?  **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868032.aspx**

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some more info ...

Comment: @noctis Is that better? basically I want to layer some geo-tagged images onto a map and then remove the map so all i can see is the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the map's `Mode` to [`MercatorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mercatormode.aspx), which removes the base map tile layer:

```
<m:Map ...>
    <m:Map.Mode>
        <m:MercatorMode/>
    </m:Map.Mode>
    ...
</m:Map>
```